# PHP and JS "Get" problem

Tags: php, get

Hello here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePage()
{
    selectedValue = document.forms['f1'].s1.value;
    newLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/PolPlan/branze.php?page="+selectedValue;
    window.locatoion = newLocation;
}
</script>

<form name="f1">
   <select name="s1" onChange="javascript:changePage()">
      <option value="1">strona 1</option>
      <option value="2">strona 2</option>
   </select>
</form>

<?php

$selectedValue = $_GET['s1']; 
echo $selectedValue;

?>
```

I get error on line:
"$selectedValue = $_GET['s1'];"
Error message: Notice: Undefined index: s1
Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$selectedValue = $_GET['s1'];
```

to

```
$selectedValue = $_GET['page'];
```

if you want to use s1 you need to submit the form

```
<form name="f1" action="/PolPlan/branze.php" method="get">
<select name="s1" onChange="document.forms['f1'].submit()">
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: page

Comment: try to submit your form like i mentioned above and you will be able to use s1

Answer (score 1):

Try using isset:

```
if (isset($_GET['s1'])) {
$selectedValue = $_GET['s1'];
echo $selectedValue;
}
```

Also be sure that the variable in your GET is the same as "s1". It looks like it should be "page".

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$selectedValue = $_GET['page'];
echo $selectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is saying that the index 's1' of the array $_GET doesn`t exists. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePage()
{
    document.forms[0].submit(); // Crossbrowser instruction
}
</script>

<form name="s1" action="http://127.0.0.1/PolPlan/branze.php">
   <select name="s1" onChange="javascript:changePage()">
      <option value="1">strona 1</option>
      <option value="2">strona 2</option>
   </select>
</form>

<?php

$selectedValue = isset($_GET['s1']) ? $_GET['s1'] : ''; 
echo $selectedValue;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePage()
{
    selectedValue = document.forms['f1'].s1.value;
    newLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/PolPlan/branze.php?page="+selectedValue;
    window.locatoion = newLocation;
}
</script>

<form name="f1">
   <select name="s1" onChange="javascript:changePage()">
      <option value="1">strona 1</option>
      <option value="2">strona 2</option>
   </select>
</form>

<?php

$selectedValue = $_GET['page']; 
echo $selectedValue;

?>
```

s1 is undefined because it doesn't exist as an element of $_GET. If you want to know the identifier of that value, it's what's on the left of the `=` in the URL, not the name of the form element (in this case – this wouldn't necessarily be the case with, say, POST)

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the value as

```
$_GET['page']
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePage()
{
    selectedValue = document.forms['f1'].s1.value;
    if (selectedValue == 0) {
        alert("Please select a valid option");
    } else {
        newLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/PolPlan/branze.php?page="+selectedValue;
        window.location = newLocation;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="f1">
   <select name="s1" onChange="javascript:changePage()">
      <option value="0">Select...</option>
      <option value="1">strona 1</option>
      <option value="2">strona 2</option>
   </select>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['s1'])) {
    $selectedValue = $_GET['s1']; 
    echo $selectedValue;
}
?>
```

You can remove the php code.

Hope works for you.